# How to merge two images base transparent python

Tags: python, opencv

I need to join two images where the base image has a transparent background, I already tried to do it using

image 01

[image]

image and a photo I need to put her in the second in the blank space
second image

[image]

expected result and this

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

dim = (425, 425)

apple = mpimg.imread('image.png')
apple = cv2.resize(apple, dim)

banana = mpimg.imread('image2.png')
banana = cv2.resize(banana, dim)


_ = plt.imshow(apple)
_ = plt.show()

_ = plt.imshow(banana)
_ = plt.show()

list_images = [apple, banana]

def blend(list_images): # Blend images equally.

    equal_fraction = 1.0 / (len(list_images))

    output = np.zeros_like(list_images[0])

    for img in list_images:
        output = output + img * equal_fraction

    output = output.astype(np.uint8)
    _ = plt.imshow(output)
    return output


output = blend(list_images)

_ = plt.imshow(output)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question or your (unrelated?) code, but if you take the **minimum** of the two images at every point, you will get black where the frame is black, and the sunset image where the frame is white.

Comment: the overlay ("frame") image in your post has no alpha channel. -- your imread calls, lacking the IMREAD_UNCHANGED flag, discard any alpha channels. -- your code does not even attempt to access any alpha channel to calculate a correct alpha-aware composition. -- matplotlib has nothing to with the issue. you only use it to display your images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily make use of your alpha (transparent) channel for this purpose. Unfortunately, when I tried reading your frame image using `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`, it didn't have the appropriate alpha channel. According to your result, the region outside the rounded corners is in white.

So using your frame image I created the alpha channel and used it the following.

```
# Reading images
tr = cv2.imread('frame.png')
la = cv2.imread('sunset.jpg')

# resizing
dim = (425, 425)
tr = cv2.resize(tr, dim)
la = cv2.resize(la, dim)

# Finding the largest contour (white region) from the first channel in frame
th = cv2.threshold(tr[:,:,0],127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)

# Draw the largest contour onto a mask
black = np.zeros((tr.shape[0], tr.shape[1]), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.drawContours(black,[c],0,255, -1)
```

Mask image: we want the sunset image to be present in the white region

[image]

```
# Create 3-channel mask of float datatype
alpha = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)/255.0

# Perform blending and limit pixel values to 0-255
blended = cv2.convertScaleAbs(tr*(1-alpha) + la*alpha)
```

[image]

Comment: How come the sun is shrinking instead of wider? But the white rectangle is not same size as previous.

Comment: I have resized both the images.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the minimalistic code needed to apply the mask:

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread("img1.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("img2.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

img1 = cv2.resize(img1, img2.shape[1::-1])
img1[img2 < 128] = 0

cv2.imshow("Image", img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Input images `img1.jpg` and `img2.png`:

[image]

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: The bottom on platform is too darker than original.